# ajaxStart is not working on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to add loader in my site and i am using ajaxStart and ajxStop request to hide and show div. but the problem is ajaxStart and ajaxStop request is not getting triggered by button onclick.
Below is my code:

```
<style>
  //css for loader
  //another class with overflow=hidden
</style>
```

now, what i want to do is:

```
$("#msg1").click(function(event){            //msg1 is the id of the button
    $body = $("body");
    $.ajaxSetup({'global':true});
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $body.addClass("loading");
    });
   });
```

but this is not working. below code works:

```
$("#msg1").click(function(event){            //msg1 is the id of the button
    alert("Hello");
});
```

So, where i am missing the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ajaxStart` will register a handler for whenever an ajax request begins, it doesn't actually fire an ajax call. With what you've written, the "loading" class will get added to the body tag if you now use any of the jQuery methods to make an ajax call.

e.g.

```
$( ".result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

UPDATE

Change your code to something like this to make it work

```
// Move these out of the click handler as they don't have to run every time
// the button is clicked.
var $body = $("body");

$.ajaxSetup({'global':true});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $body.addClass("loading");
});

$("#msg1").click(function(event){
    // Here is where you actually make the ajax call, so the "loading" class
    // will now be added to the body tag.
    $.ajax( "example.php" )
      .done(function(data) {
        // Do something with the data you've just retrieved.
        // You probably now want to remove the "loading" class too.
    })
});
```

Comment: I exactly want to do that. I want to add "loading" class to the body using ajaxStart.

Comment: but i don't know why ajaxStart is not getting triggered

Comment: Because you haven't yet made an ajax call, all you've done is said "When I make an ajax call, add the 'loading' class to the body". You still have to make the ajax call itself, does that make sense?

Comment: I've update your code to show you how this works, hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. and i found my mistake.